# proof that there exists a regular expression r for every NFA with only 2 states

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, regular-expressions

*Let L be a regular language. Then there exists a regular expression r such that L = L(r).*

**Proof for NFAs with only 2 states (can be generalized!), partly seen during a lecture and completed by me:**

Let $M=\left(Q, \sigma, \delta, q_0, F\right)$ be an nfa that accepts $L$

The nfa $M$ has only two states $q_0$ and $q_1$ with $F=\left\{q_1\right\}$. We now claim that the language accepted by $M$ is given by the regular expression
$$
r:=r_{00}^* r_{01}\left(r_{11}+r_{10} r_{00}^* r_{01}\right)^* .
$$
Let us formally prove that $L(M)=L(r)$.
First, assume $w \in L(M)$, i.e., there exists a walk $W$ through $M$ that witnesses acceptance. Since $M$ only has two states, we know that this walk must be of the form
$$
W=q_0^{n_1} q_1^{n_2} q_0^{n_3} \ldots q_1^{n_k}
$$
with $n_k>0$ and hence $w$ satisfies the regular expression
$$
\underbrace{r_{00}, \ldots, r_{00}}_{n_1-1 \text { times }} r_{01} \underbrace{r_{11}, \ldots, r_{11}}_{n_2-1 \text { times }}(r_{10} \underbrace{r_{00}, \ldots, r_{00}}_{n_3-1 \text { times }} r_{01}) \ldots
$$

**My question:**

For the other direction, so if $w \in L(r)$, can I just use the same arguments as in the other (given in the proof) direction? So:
There exists a walk $W$ through $M$ that witnesses acceptance. Since $M$ only has two states, we know that the walk must be of the form
$$
W=q_0^{n_1} q_1^{n_2} q_0^{n_3} \ldots q_1^{n_k}
$$
and this walk satisfies w.

Comment: I think it should be that given any  $w \in L(r) $,  show that it induces a walk $W$ that starts with $q_0$ and ends up at $q_1$. Since what your trying to do is the direction from regular expression to regular language.

Comment: Thank you. Would you be willing to give me some guidance on how to do that?

Comment: You can start with letting $w \in L(r)$ be some string. Then, $w$ should have the following form $r_{00}^ar_{01}(r_{11}+r_{10}r_{00}^br_{01})^c$, where $a,b,c\ge0$. From this show that you can construct $W$ for the different cases with respect to the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: @Russel Thank you. But the problem is that I do not really know how to "show" such a thing. Should I just use the techniques I have seen in class to convert a regular expression to a NFA?

Comment: @Russel And why should there be different cases?